# What properties does $a(n)$ have to fullfill to get $\log(2^{cn}+a(n))\sim\log(2^{cn})$?

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

Let $c$ be an exponential growth rate, and $a(n)$ any expression in $n$ (sequence, polynom, function,...).

Consider
$$
\log(2^{cn}+a(n)).
$$
I am asking myself what properties (increasing, decreasing, etc.) must be fullfilled for $a(n)$ in order to have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(2^{cn}+a(n))}{\log(2^{cn})}=1,
$$
(notation for that: $\log(2^{cn}+a(n))\sim\log(2^{cn})$.

Isn't is necessary that $a(n)$ grows slower than $2^{cn}$ or equal as $2^{cn}$, i.e. $a(n)\in O(2^{cn})$?

Comment: $a(n)=2^{cn}$ is possible.

Comment: It is clear. Let us put $a \left( n \right) ={2}^{cn}r \left( n \right) $.   Assuming $c>0$, the limit under consideration equals $1$ if $\log|r(n)| =o(n)$ as $n \to \infty .$

Comment: why $\log\lvert r(n)\rvert=o(n)$ and not $r(n)=o(n)$?